# How to use vue axios to send xml format requests?

Tags: xml, vue.js, cors, axios

I sent a "put" request and received a cors issue:

[image]

This is the payload header:

[image]

[image]

I sure it's not a header issue and checked with my backend engineer. He says gcp upload (google cloud platform) needs xml formatted request(XHR). And I found axios' default is the JSON format.

Then I tried to find some workable solution like sending formData as payload.

[How to send a file via Axios to Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907747/how-to-send-a-file-via-axios-to-laravel)

But it still doesn't work. Is there any sample of sending xml format request with vue axios?

If not, I have to turn back to use "new XMLHttpRequest();".

Thanks

Comment: Cross-origin PUT requests *always* trigger a preflight.

Comment: Can it be resolved by client site which set header in axios? (I have try to send header like "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" and backend engineer say he already set.) Or It can't use by axios to send request?

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a response header, not a request header. The server has to give your JS permission. It can't give itself permission.

Comment: You're right, sorry I mean setting  "Content-Type" and backend site is already set. So it can't resolve by axios ? Should I use "new XMLHttpRequest()" ..?

Comment: Here is some information: I'm not sure can axios sending request to gcp upload?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44705528/google-cloud-storage-ignoring-access-control-origin-headers